# Google hangout referrer traffic

Tags: analytics, referrer

I show a modal window to those referring from Google search on my landing page.  The problem is that when someone comes from Google hangout or gmail, the modal window pops up as well.  I don't see a distinct difference in the full referral path of Google search or Google hangouts/gmail.

How can I differentiate the referrals?

Google search does use different parameters within their search redirect, but they do not pass these in the referral header.